# Removal from Mongo to Elasticsearch

Tags: php, mongodb, elasticsearch, internal

I'm a novice when it comes to Mongo and Elasticsearch and I have a problem.

I move Mongo's collection to ES index. There are 30 milions documents in collection. Initially, the script moves 15 milions files swiftly and without a break. After 15 milions, "500 internal error" shows more often. I was able to move 28 milions files with help of PHP script, after which I get "500 internal error". Error logs are empty. Memory limit for PHP is set on 1,2 GB and i can not enlarge it.

Fragment of the script where error shows up looks something like this:

```
$db->createCollection($collectionName);
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, $collectionName);
$cursor = $collection->find()->skip($nextPortion)->limit($pageing);
while ($value = $cursor->getNext())
{
        ...........
    make JSON
    ...........
}
```

Script can't move through this line. In this line I get server error:

```
while ($value = $cursor->getNext())
```

I move files using bulk API in ES.

Is there any way of finishing moving the files other than through increasing the memory for PHP?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in batches instead of all at once, run a cronjob evrery 5 minutes for however long. This means you are less likely to suffer problems due to network and cursor life times.

Also using skip() is probably a bad idea on 28 million records, I am unsure what `$nextPortion` is but it can't be a good thing to use in conjunction with all those records.

Comment: @user2622824 I would definitely use ranges of _id instead, that could be whats causing the problem

Comment: Also, this is not an operation that should be executed through a web server (taking "500 server error" as a hint). PHP in the CLI environment should be more flexible when it comes to script execution time. MongoCursor lifetimes can be adjusted with [MongoCursor::timeout()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php), but it's difficult to identify the cause unless the actual error is provided. Empty error logs are likely the result of a configuration problem. I expect that [`$cursor->hasNext()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.hasnext.php) is throwing a timeout exception.